# How to write time.series object with date column to an excel file in R?

Tags: r, excel, package

There are several functions to write data.frames to excel, e.g. write.xls from the xlsx package. However, when I write a time series it saves the data with row names 1,2,3,.. instead of the dates. How can dates be saved as row names?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example use `as.yearmon` from the `lubridate` package:

```
require(lubridate)
require(zoo)

col_names <- as.yearmon(time(my_ts))
```

Now you can create a new data frame as:

```
data.frame(col_names, my_ts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a data frame with two columns - date and value from the time series.

```
# Retrieve start date and end date from time series
start_date <- as.Date(start(tsobject)[1])
end_date <- start_date+length(tsobject)-1

# Make a data frame with two columns - date and value
df <- data.frame(date=seq(from=start_date, to=end_date, by=1),
                 value=tsobject)

# Write data to excel
write.xlsx(df, filename)
```